# google calendar api: calendars vs calendarList

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I was messing around trying to add a new calendar and it took me quite a while to figure out that I had to add it to 'Calendars' and not to 'CalendarList'. It works now, which is nice, but I what is the difference between the two concepts? It seems to me I only need Calendars? Also, CalendarList doesn't seem to work, trying to insert a Calendar returned a 404 error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Calendars is a collection of all calendars in the world (it does not have a list method). When creating a new calendar, you should call an insert on the calendars collection. When you want calendar specific data (such as the timezone, the name) then you should retrieve a calendar from calendars collection using get.

CalendarLists is a collection of all calendar entries that a user added to their list (in the web UI it's the list of calendars in the left panel). You cannot create a new calendar through the calendar list collection but you can add an existing calendar to the list of your users calendars. Each user can for example have a different color for the same calendar and this detail will be stored in the calendar list entries.

What is sometimes confusing is that when you create a new calendar through calendars collection, it will be automatically added to your list.

Let me give you an example of how Calendars and CalendarLists work. Imagine your friend creates a calendar for a trip that you will be going on together. He does so by doing a Calendars.insert() call.
Now he makes the calendar public (via ACLs collection) and sends you and all the friends an email of this calendar. You can go into the CalendarLists collection and do an insert() call there to add it into your list of calendars and make it blue.

Answer (score 1):

Calendars:

> The Calendars collection represents all existing calendars. It can be
> used to create and delete calendars. You can also retrieve or set
> global properties shared across all users with access to a calendar.
> For example, a calendar's title and default time zone are global
> properties.

CalendarList:

> The CalendarList is a collection of all calendar entries that a user
> has added to their list (shown in the left panel of the web UI). You
> can use it to add and remove existing calendars to/from the users’
> list. You also use it to retrieve and set the values of user-specific
> calendar properties, such as default reminders. Another example is
> foreground color, since different users can have different colors set
> for the same calendar.

Here the comparison table:
[https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars)